How to use Telethon on Github Actions
I have a script that makes some files and it runs on GitHub actions.
after those files have been made, I want to send them with another scrips in telegram for some group with my own telegram account.
Telegrams shows me a dialog that asks for bot token or phone number. then it sends me a message with a code that i have to enter the code. but as I'm running the code scheduled on GitHub actions there is no way for me to enter my phone number. the output is:
Run python Send_Telagram_Message.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Send_Telagram_Message.py", line 33, in <module>
with client:
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/helpers.py", line 219, in _sync_enter
return loop.run_until_complete(self.__aenter__())
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
return future.result()
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 657, in __aenter__
return await self.start()
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 165, in _start
value = phone()
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.8.18/x64/lib/python3.8/site-packages/telethon/client/auth.py", line 22, in <lambda>
phone: typing.Callable[[], str] = lambda: input('Please enter your phone (or bot token): '),
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
Please enter your phone (or bot token): 
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

I used telethon library. and my code is:
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import os

# Set up the Telegram client with your own account credentials
api_id = os.environ['API_ID']
api_hash = os.environ['API_HASH']
phone_number = os.environ['PHONE_NUMBER']

client = TelegramClient('send things', api_id, api_hash)

async def main():
    # Log in to your Telegram account
    await client.start(phone_number)

    # Replace 'group_username' with the username of your group
    group_id = -4119703192
    group_entity = await client.get_entity(group_id)

    # Path to the folder containing images
    folder_path = os.path.join(current_directory, 'To_Send')

    # Iterate through the images in the folder
    for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
        if filename.endswith('.jpg') or filename.endswith('.png'):
            image_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)

            # Send the image to the group
            await client.send_file(group_entity, file=image_path)

    print("All images sent to the group.")

# Run the main function
with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())

And this is my workflow:
name: Send_Telagram_Message.py

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '* * * * *' #10min

jobs:
  run_script:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: 3.8

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          pip install telethon
          
      - name: Run script
        env:
          API_ID: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_API_ID }}
          API_HASH: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_API_HASH }}
          PHONE_NUMBER: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_PHONE_NUMBER }}
        run: python Send_Telagram_Message.py


Please include your workflow in your question. Sounds like you can simply pass the input like this echo "code" | ./your-script. Something like that should work.

Im sorry. I'll edit it now. But if I echo my telephone number, what can I do about the verification code?

You should be able to automate this by entering the values you need. You should first automate this locally and then use the same steps to automate in your GHA workflow.

Thanks alot for your advice. Yes I did that, as people say "it works on my machine". But it needs authentication at the first run.

Right. Please add the console after running your script. That might be helpful to suggest some fixes. Apparently, the library you're using is internally prompting to ask for inputs e.g. Please enter your phone (or bot token):. Also, you might need to go through the APIs of this library to check if there's something there to fetch these values from some env var or some other non-interactive way.

Actually I was thinking about making an online file and passing phone number with echo then checking my telegram for the authentication code. When I received it, writing that on the online file and getting it with My code and pass it with echo again. But thanks I'll try your suggestion too.
